# Ожидание перед парсингом

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Делаю парсинг сайта через requests + bs4.
Столкнулся с такой задачей: часть кода сайта записано в script и парсинг просто выдаёт пустое значение из-за того, что сам script сайта прогружается **не вместе** с html кодом.
Другими словами, я получаю `<div class="tab-cont"> </div>`. Через простой браузер значения в этом поле я получаю через несколько секунд после прогрузки страницы, но через парсер получаю пустое значение.

Каким образом можно сделать вход на страницу, но выполнение get запроса через несколько секунд?

```
url = 'site.com'
r = request.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
info = soup.find('div', class_ = 're-tab-cont')

>>> info = <div class="detail-tab-cont"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы парсить сайт, который подгружается динамически - вам нужно использовать **selenium**, и там есть специальный модуль `implicitly_wait()`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(5.5)
```

Так же можете использовать решение из коробки с помощью `time`

```
from time import sleep

time.sleep(5.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Остановка выполнения задачи делается при помощи модуля time.
time.sleep(5) #остановка на 5 секунд

Comment: Как ты впихнешь time.sleep в get запрос? .....